# AppFabric configuration issue with dataCacheClient vs dataCacheClients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I'm trying to get AppFabric working in my Asp.net application, everything works fine if I use c# code to do the configuration.  But I'm having a real hard time to get it to work from web.config.  If I have the following in the web.config,

```
<section name="dataCacheClient"
            type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
        Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            />
```

and

```
 <dataCacheClient>
  <hosts>
    <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" />
  </hosts>
</dataCacheClient>
```

then my code does not throw exceptions, HOWEVER doing put to the default cache does not actually put anything into the cache, byte count is 0.

If I change the web.config to

```
<section name="dataCacheClients"
            type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
        Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            />
```

notice the it's "**dataCacheClients**" with an "s" and

```
 <dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <hosts>
    <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" />
  </hosts>
</dataCacheClient>
```

I got exception

```
ErrorCode<ERRCA0021>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Server collection cannot be empty
```

Could someone help point out what I'm missing here.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is correct, just add parameters: 
allowLocation="true"
allowDefinition="Everywhere".

```
<section name="dataCacheClient"
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
               Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         allowLocation="true"
         allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
```